# gnome-terminal profile without bash history

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to create a profile in `gnome-terminal` that doesn't store bash history.

The easiest way to do that is to run `export HISTIGNORE="*"`, but there is one problem, `gome-terminal` is executing command before running bash, so this variable is being overwritten.

I was thinking about using `.profile` or `.bashrc`, but I don't want it to execute every time bash starts and I don't know how to determine which profile is being used by `gnome-terminal` from within terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `env` to run the shell in a custom environment e.g. `/usr/bin/env HISTIGNORE='*' /bin/bash` from the gnome-terminal `Title and Command` tab?

[image: gnome-terminal custom command]

This seems to work for me - although I can't help feeling there's a more efficient way that doesn't involve testing each command against the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks, it still will not work because `$HISTIGNORE` is being overwritten, but now I can pass other variable like `gprofile=no_hist` and add `[ "$gprofile" == "no_hist" ] && export HISTIGNORE='*'` at the end of `.bashrc`, so thank you again for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit

```
/etc/profile
```

file with root privilege. It is system-wide profile. Runs before *~/.profile*

Comment: Why? `Gnome-terminal` command runs before shell including `/etc/profile` and I don't want it to run for all profiles every time, just when I choose specific profile.